# .NET Core 2.0 Encoding.GetEncoding

Tags: c#, кодировка, .net-core

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой: нужно отправлять сообщение на почтовый ящик в кодировке `koi8-u`(21866). Использую пакет `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages`:

```
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
        MailAddress fr = new MailAddress("***@**.com", "Name");
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("***@**.com");
        MailMessage m = new MailMessage(fr, to)
        {
            Body = "test",
            BodyEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("koi8-u")
        };
        await smtp.SendMailAsync(m);
```

Но при отправке получаю: *No data is available for encoding 21866. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.*

В обычном .NET Framework-е все отлично отправляется, в .NET Core увы. Как можно решить это?

**P.S:** такая же ситуация и для `windows-1252` и прочих.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Просто подключите в проект *NuGet*-пакет с расширенными кодировками:

> System.Text.Encoding.CodePages

И перед использованием зарегистрируйте их:

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```

Должно помочь.

Comment: В своем примере я уже использую `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages` и `Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance)`.

Comment: значит проблема в другом месте, потому что у меня ваш код работает - http://take.ms/6BcPAc

Comment: не мешало бы добавить в вопрос детали про установленный пакет, потому что не по глазам, честно сказать, в коде не заметил